# Passing variables from controller to view that works with DOMPDF in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, pdf-generation, dompdf, invoices

Best regards!
Today I'm with an issue trying to generate invoices in PDF with DOMPDF.

Let's explain:
I have a view that i select the invoice id. When I click the "generate PDF" button it goes this way:

(takes you to controller)

```
foreach ($this->input->post('check') as $key)
    {

    $testLayout = load_modulo('bankX', 'invoice_bankX'); //here I call the file in views dir(bankX) and the view inside the file (case 'invoice_bankX') that brings me the bank invoice layout
    $filename = 'invoice_'.$key;
    pdf_create($testLayout, $filename, TRUE);

    }
```

(the load_modulo function)

```
function load_modulo($modulo = NULL, $tela = NULL, $diretorio = 'panel') {

$CI = & get_instance();

if ($modulo != NULL) {

    return $CI->load->view("$diretorio/$modulo", array('tela' => $tela), TRUE);
} else {


    return FALSE;
    }
}
```

(the pdf_create function)

```
function pdf_create($html, $filename = '', $stream = TRUE) {
require_once("dompdf/dompdf_config.inc.php");

$dompdf = new DOMPDF();
$dompdf->load_html($html);
$dompdf->render();

if ($stream) {
    $dompdf->stream($filename . ".pdf");
} else {

    $output = $dompdf->output();
    file_put_contents('Brochure.pdf', $output);


}
```

Now knowing that I have more data to pass through to the 'invoice_bankX' view (I need 1 var that retain the bank and client values that I can callback in this view to mount the invoice with the client and store datas )

i.e.

$invoiceData = array();

$invoiceData['invoice_number'] = 344;

$invoiceData['client_name'] = 'John Masters';

Because this way I can pass the values to mount the invoice correctly.
Anyone knows how to?

*note - right now, if I click the button to generate invoice(PDF), this works. But the invoice comes with the static data that I wrote to test

Comment: You are not fetching data from the database.

Comment: @mdamia Yes, I'm not yet. My primary doubt is 'how to pass the post check var to the view'? Because this way I can fetch database data by check id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to do this by setting the number of the invoice on session.
The controller now looks like this and it works:

```
foreach ($this->input->post('check') as $key)
    {

        $dataInvoice = array('invoice_number' => $key);
        $this->session->set_userdata($dataInvoice);

        $testLayout = load_modulo('bankX', 'invoice_bankX');
        $filename = 'invoice_'.$key;
        pdf_create($testLayout, $filename, TRUE);

    }
```

So that way I could call at the view the

```
$invoice_number = $this->session->userdata('invoice_number');
```

and do all the queries that i want